# Can I obtain a new Italian residency card from an Italian consulate abroad?

Tags: usa, paperwork, italy, italian-residents, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am going overseas for 3 months, but my permesso di soggiorno is expired in 2.5 months. I don't want to come back to Italy in the middle of my mission just to get the new permesso di soggiorno (and then travel again). What could I do in this situation? is it possible to obtain permesso di soggiorno from that country instead of coming back to Italy?

Comment: You may be able to get a visa at a consulate and then get a new permesso after you return, or you may be able to renew the permesso before you leave.  The second option is probably simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through the process to obtain your permesso di soggiorno, you'll understand what it takes, and that it has to be done in Italy. After going through all the [process to renew your residency permit](http://www.portaleimmigrazione.it/ImmigrazioneNet/APR_Aggiornamento_CDS_en.aspx), it can take months for the card to be issued. Apply before leaving Italy, and make sure you keep the receipt from the post office or police department, confirming that you've applied for the new permesso. That is what you'll need to be able to re-enter Italy.

The IATA (International Air Transport Association) [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/) database, used by airline check-in agents, notes:

> Alien residents of Italy holding expired Residence Permits or a copy of an expired Residence Permit are permitted to re-enter Italy, provided also holding a receipt issued by the Italian Post Office or Police Department, confirming new permit has been applied for. Applications for renewal must be made within 60 days of expiring, otherwise immigration could refuse re-entry, even if holding confirmation of application. Holders [of] copies of an expired Residence Permit also require a statement, stating that they are holding a copy…”

This is confirmed by Directive of the Italian Government’s Interior Ministry –

A directive from the [Ministero dell’Interno, 5 agosto 2006, N. Prot. 11050/M(8)](https://www.poliziadistato.it/statics/31/carta_circular_9_8_06.pdf) states that one may leave and return to Italy with an expired Permesso di Soggiorno, as long as one has the receipt (ricevuta):

> Lo straniero in possesso del permesso di soggiorno, ancorché scaduto, e della ricevuta di presentazione dell’istanza di rinnovo, ha la facoltà di lasciare il territorio dello Stato e di farvi regolare rientro, alle condizioni più volte reiterate con le circolari del Dipartimento della Pubblica Sicurezza.

In translation: The foreigner who has the residence permit, even though it has expired, and the receipt of the renewal application, has the right to leave the territory of the state and to return, under the conditions stated previously within the Circulars of the Department of Public Affairs Safety.